# Unable to target the project to android 8.0 in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Studio Professional Version 6.3 (build 863) and Xamarin.Android Version: 8.0.0.33 (Visual Studio Professional). I have installed as well all the elements for the Android 8.0 SDK through the SDK Tools but even with that, I can't target my android app to be an Android 8.0 app. In the manifest file, the target version for 8.0 is itself not showing. To make sure I have downloaded all SDK tools I created a project in Android studio and targeted to 8.0 and was able to run in successfully in 8.0 device.The following was the error I got when I run the application on 8.0 device.

> Deploying package to 'ENU7N15B10002409'
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: OS version not recognized: 8.0 
>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidVersion.OSVersionToApiLevel(String
>   osVersion) in
>   C:\data\lanes\4469\a2163670\source\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\external\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\AndroidVersion.cs:line
>   43    at
>   MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidUtility.d__16.MoveNext() in
>   C:\data\lanes\4469\a2163670\source\md-addins\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\MonoDroidUtility.cs:line
>   416
>
> Deployment failed, unsupported framework version '8.0'

Can you please tell me what am I missing in the xamarin studio.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set SDK target framework to Android 8.0 as well. 
It's located in a different tab, and I suppose for a new project its set automatically to the highest depending on what you have, but since your project was created before you download the latest one, it may still target the lower one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Taier , this is what i was looking for